# Find max value for one column among rows where other values are equal

Tags: awk

Maybe some could help me with a unique awk script for the following. I have the below input, where the second field tells dimensions in pixels (w,h) and position (x,y), for example: 892x584+1002+922.

From this text I need extract the parameters w,h,x,y with the following conditions:

1. Get `w,h,x,y` for those lines that have `code(wxy)`
2. From output in step 1 get those where `w >= 250`
3. From output in step 2, find pairs of lines where `w>=800` AND that have equal values for `w`, `h` and `y` but different value in `x`
4. From the comparison in step 3, between each pair, only print lines that have the bigger value in `x`.

This is the input:

```
0: 1920x1664+0+0 867.6,708.6 751192 code(abc)
633: 892x584+1002+922 1447.5,1213.5 520928 code(wxy)
632: 892x584+71+922 516.5,1213.5 520928 code(wxy)
21: 892x485+1002+376 1447.5,618.0 432620 code(wxy)
20: 892x485+71+376 516.5,618.0 432620 code(wxy)
15: 429x144+535+155 749.0,226.5 61776 code(wxy)
16: 428x144+1001+155 1214.5,226.5 61632 code(wxy)
17: 428x144+1467+155 1680.5,226.5 61632 code(wxy)
14: 428x144+70+155 283.5,226.5 61632 code(wxy)
1230: 892x60+71+1522 516.5,1551.5 53520 code(abc)
1231: 892x60+1002+1522 1447.5,1551.5 53520 code(abc)
19: 892x45+1002+330 1447.5,352.0 40140 code(wxy)
630: 892x45+71+876 516.5,898.0 40140 code(wxy)
631: 892x45+1002+876 1447.5,898.0 40140 code(wxy)
18: 892x45+71+330 516.5,352.0 40140 code(wxy)
4: 274x40+1620+111 1756.5,130.5 10960 code(wxy)
2: 144x40+1332+111 1403.5,130.5 5760 code(wxy)
3: 140x40+1478+111 1547.5,130.5 5600 code(wxy)
```

I'm stuck in how to reach step 4. Previous to get step 4, I sorted first by `y` and then by `x`.

My current script (piping twice) is this:

```
awk -F[" x+"] '/code\(wxy\)/{print $2,$3,$4,$5}' | sort -k4 -k3 -n | awk '$1>250{print $1,$2,$3,$4}'
```

and current output is:

```
274 40 1620 111
428 144 70 155
429 144 535 155
428 144 1001 155
428 144 1467 155
892 45 71 330
892 45 1002 330
892 485 71 376
892 485 1002 376
892 45 71 876
892 45 1002 876
892 584 71 922
892 584 1002 922
```

My expected output would be all lines in green, since the lines in yellow has `w<250` and lines in blue are the ones that have a "sister line" but with a smaller `x`:

```
274 40 1620 111
428 144 70 155
429 144 535 155
428 144 1001 155
428 144 1467 155
892 45 1002 330
892 485 1002 376
892 45 1002 876
892 584 1002 922
```

I hope make sense. Thanks for any help.

Comment: Why aren't these filtered out?  
`428 144 70 155`  and `428 144 1001 155`

Comment: Please [don't post images of code, error messages, or other textual data.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors) The color-coding is a nice visualization, but it would be nicer still to have an exposition which works even for those of us with visual impairments, at least as a fallback.

Comment: @karakfa Yes, I forget to add that in condition 3, "w" should be greater than 800, I've updated in my question.

Comment: Ohhh, ok, I get it. I put the image thinking would be more easier to understand.

Comment: Step 3. is unclear. For inputs `16:`, `17:` and `14:`, the largest "sister" value for `X` is contained in `428 144 1467 155`, but the "Expected Output" shows the sister records with the `X` values of `1000` and `70` also included. That violates `"between each pair, only print lines that have the bigger value in x"`??

Comment: I edited the step 3 in original question to be more clear for all. The find of "pair" should be only for lines where W >800....

Comment: Thank you, that does clarify and change things, I was looking for `else if (abs(w[n] - x[n]) > 800)` before considering a candidate for a pair under your original step 3.

Comment: @EdMorton I edited the step 3 in original question to be more clear for all. The find of "pair" should be only for lines where W >800. In 2nd step ai need to get only lines with W>250. I refer to the yellow lines that should be excluded since W<250 for them. Is the same condition that allow lines with W>250.

Comment: What is the output, just `w, h, x, y`? Step 4. says "... only print **lines** that have the bigger value in `x`", so that indicates print the full record matching 1-4. Either way is easy enough, but which is right?

Comment: @EdMorton I edited step 2 and 3 to look for W>=250 and then find pairs with W>=800

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Yes, would be print the full record from 1 to 4. Thank you

Comment: Hang on - your expected output is just the 4 values, not the full line/record. Which do you want? Please make sure your expected output shows that.

Comment: Yes the 4 values w,h,x,y. Your output is correct. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know for sure what your requirement is for [the min or max value of `w`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77625677/find-max-value-for-one-column-among-rows-where-other-values-are-equal/77627792#comment136853962_77625677) but hopefully this will be easy enough for you to modify to whatever it is if I guessed wrong:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

awk '
    $NF == "code(wxy)" {
        split($2,whxy,/[x+]/)
        w = whxy[1]
        h = whxy[2]
        x = whxy[3]
        y = whxy[4]

        if ( w >= 250 ) {
            val = w OFS h OFS x OFS y
            if ( w < 800 ) {
                print val
            }
            else {
                key = w OFS h OFS y
                if ( !(key in maxs) || (x > maxs[key]) ) {
                    maxs[key] = x
                    vals[key] = val
                }
            }
        }
    }
    END {
        for ( key in maxs ) {
            print vals[key]
        }
    }
' "${@:--}"
```

```
$ ./tst.sh file
429 144 535 155
428 144 1001 155
428 144 1467 155
428 144 70 155
274 40 1620 111
892 45 1002 876
892 45 1002 330
892 485 1002 376
892 584 1002 922
```

Comment: Hmmm, Why `OFS` instead of `SUBSEP`? (yes, defaults are both `","`) I was close, but got hung up on "pair" definition. Good job!

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin we're going to be printing one of the concatenated strings, `val`, so we want the separator in that case to be `OFS` since that's what you'd expect separating fields in the output. Given that I used OFS in `key` too for consistency.

Comment: Makes perfect sense. `OFS` is more digestible than `SUBSEP` for many learning awk as well. Thanks.

Comment: Rule of thumb I try to follow for concatenated strings: If you're going to output it and `OFS` can't be present in one of the values being concatenated then use `OFS`, otherwise if `RS` is a string rather than a regexp then use `RS`, otherwise if `FS` is a string use `FS`. I'd only use `SUBSEP` implicitly if I was creating a concatenated array index with `arr[x,y,z]`, I'd never actually write `x SUBSEP y SUBSEP z` unless none of OFS, RS, or FS works since it's more typing for no benefit and, though unlikely, technically could be present in a field.

Comment: Thank you. I approached it with the array, e.g. `pair[w[n],h[n],y[n]]` and then `if (w[n] SUBSEP h[n] SUBSEP y[n] in pair)` which is what peeked my curiosity with `key = w OFS h OFS y`. I just haven't learned the typing reduction tricks yet -- still too literal...

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin I avoid using `SUBSEP` except for implicitly mostly because it could appear in a field whereas neither RS (if a string) nor FS (if a string) nor OFS (usually) can, the reduced typing is just gravy.

Answer (score 2):

**UPDATED** based on the change

```
$ awk -F'[ x+]' '/code\(wxy\)/ && $2>250 {print $2,$3,$4,$5}' file | 
  sort -k1n -k2n -k4n -k3rn | 
  awk '$1<800 || !a[$1,$2,$4]++'

274 40 1620 111
428 144 1467 155
428 144 1001 155
428 144 70 155
429 144 535 155
892 45 1002 330
892 45 1002 876
892 485 1002 376
892 584 1002 922
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution. I forget to add that in condition 3, "w" should be greater than 800, I've updated in my question.

Answer (score 1):

Awk itself has good support for this, by way of its associative arrays. Here's an attempt to implement the logic you describe.

```
awk '/code\(wxy\)/ {
    split($2, whxy, /[+x]/)
    if (whxy[1] > 800) {
      k = whxy[1] " " whxy[2] " " whxy[4]
      if (why[k] < whxy[3]) {
        why[k] = whxy[3]
        a[k] = whxy[1] " " whxy[2] " " whxy[3] " " whxy[4]
      }
    }
 }
 END { for(k in a) print a[k] }' file
```

This doesn't sort its output, but it's obviously easy to pipe the end result to `sort` if you want that.

This collects the current maximum `x` for a particular combination of `w` x `h` + *x* + `y` in the array `why`, and the corresponding complete *w* x *h* + *x* + *y* matrix in `a`, which gets overwritten every time we find a bigger `x` for this `w` x `h` + *x* + `y` combination. Then in the `END` block, we print out the collected matrices.

With your sample input, and a pipe to `sort`, I get

```
892 45 1002 330
892 45 1002 876
892 485 1002 376
892 584 1002 922
```

which differs slightly from your expected result, but appears to agree with your prose formulation of your requirements.

Demo: https://ideone.com/rnnAgS

Comment: Thank you for your solution and explanation, I see that your output is different because I forget to add in condition 3, that `w`should be greater than 800, I've updated in my question.

Comment: Going forward, don't do that; instead, (accept the answer you got, or post an answer of your own and accept that if you prefer, and) post a new question with your actual requirements. But this time, I can update the answer to still answer the question.

Comment: (If `w` needs to be bigger than 800, then the requirement for it to be bigger than 250 is redundant.)

Comment: I edited the step 3 in original question to be more clear for all. The find of "pairs" should be only for lines where W >800...